# iOS - Capture UIWebView to Image

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm attempting to capture **the entire UIWebView (even off screen content)** to a PNG.  The following code works great on most devices however on some iPad 1st gens it crashed on this line:

```
[self.webview.layer renderInContext:resizedContext]; /// crash
```

**How can I prevent the crash by stopping the renderInContext process?**

See the code sample below for context of the issue:

```
//Create original tmp bounds
CGRect tmpFrame = self.webview.frame;
CGRect tmpBounds = self.webview.bounds;
CGRect aFrame = self.webview.bounds;
aFrame.size.width = self.webview.frame.size.width;
aFrame.size.height = self.webview.frame.size.height;
self.webview.frame = aFrame;
aFrame.size.height = [self.webview sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size].height;

NSLog(@"webpage size %f",self.webview.frame.size.height);

self.webview.frame = aFrame;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([self.webview sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size]);
CGContextRef resizedContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// crash
[self.webview.layer renderInContext:resizedContext]; // crash
// crash

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
self.webview.frame = tmpFrame;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",@"TestImage"]];
NSError *error;
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pngPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pngPath];

//reset webview
self.webview.bounds = tmpBounds;
self.webview.frame = tmpFrame;
```

**Simulator does not crash, Here are the logging errors from console when run on device:**

```
May 16 12:33:41 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'AppName' exited abnormally     with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
May 16 12:33:41 unknown DTMobileIS[652] <Warning>: _memoryNotification : {
    OSMemoryNotificationLevel = 0;
    timestamp = "2012-05-16 19:33:41 +0000";
}
May 16 12:33:41 unknown DTMobileIS[652] <Warning>: _memoryNotification : <NSThread: 0x1d5286d0>{name = (null), num = 1}
May 16 12:33:41 unknown DTMobileIS[652] <Warning>: _memoryNotification : {
    OSMemoryNotificationLevel = 0;
    timestamp = "2012-05-16 19:33:41 +0000";
}
```

Comment: What is the exception when it crashes?

Comment: No exception which is strange. It's like the app reaches an out of memory exception and rather than calling didReceiveMemoryWarning it simply crashes with no log.

Comment: Consider wrapping the line in a @try/@catch block and seeing if that produces an exception to analyze.  Might not help; can't hurt.  (The last time I had any faith in Xcode's exception reporting ability was 3.x.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Phillip however the app crashed in the try block and immediately crashes with no error and does not enter the catch block. This is very frustrating!

Comment: And nothing interesting logged by the system on the iPad console, I assume....  Any difference if the iPad is freshly rebooted (least amount of other stuff in memory)?

Comment: Does the crash also happen in the ios4 simulator? And when the device is attached to the macbook, is there nothing shown on the console?

Comment: Does not crash in the simulator only on device.

Comment: I do appear to be getting some memeory exception from the console on device. I updated the question with the log results

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this same issue doing something similar, and resolved it by first calculating if the image will be more than about 8,000 pixels in height.

If so I failed and warned the user that the page was too large for this process whenever it was an iPad 1 hardware version.

I never found any real solution to the issue.